# One word for the ta-daa! pose?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I can hardly describe this, which is why I need the one word. When you shout "Ta-daa!" and throw your arms out at your sides, does anyone have a one-word description for what you're doing? Argh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, it would be a flourish, but I believe the specific gesture you're talking about is sometimes described as "jazz hands".

Comment: I would call it "finishing with a flourish" (I know, not a single word). But "jazz hands" is really not the same thing.

Comment: I agree that jazz hands is different.  Jazz hands has kind of twinkly fingers.  *Flourish* is the word that jumped to my mind, too, but doesn't necessarily involve a "ta-da!"