# Origin of 'tada'

Tags: etymology, interjections

What is the origin of the word *tada* — as used as an exclamation? Is it an onomatopoeic form of sound effects used in, say, television or does its origin lie elsewhere?

Comment: I'd go with the onomatopoeic explanation. The pronunciation always includes a long final 'aah' sound.

Comment: Related: _[One word for the ta-daa! pose?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/28137/5822)_

Comment: Perhaps there's a case for saying it's a contraction of *"Da da-da-da da-da da DAH!"?*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"Tada" is indeed an onomatopoeia (from OED):

> Imitative of the sound of the musical flourish or fanfare (composed of one short note followed by one long note) which often accompanies an entrance, trick, etc., in various kinds of performance.

The word is imitating this classic [horn sound](http://soundbible.com/1003-Ta-Da.html).

Here is the first citation in 1913:

> Coming front in utter disgust, he [sc. a conjuror] tells them [sc. the orchestra] that that won't do, that he wants something like ‘tadaa!’ from all of them. They seem to understand, so he goes off again. On his reappearance, however, he is met with a loud tumult, as all the orchestra shout out in unison the word ‘tadaa!’.

Comment: Note: _sc._ means "namely".  (It is an abbreviation of the Latin _scilicet_.)

Comment: It's funny - I always assumed that musical sting was simply AN ATTEMPT TO SOUND LIKE "wala" (or "tada").  It seems extremely obvious that that is the case.  The only reason the musical sting. makes you think of the concept "wala" or "tada" is because - it sounds like it.  the idea that a musical pattern - on it's own - would, sort of platonically, suggest some meaning -- is bizarre.

Comment: @Joe: 2 questions - first, when you say 'voila' or 'wala', is the first sound for you a 'v' as in 'van' (a big truck) or the 'w' in 'wan' (pale)? (the two sounds in English and French are distinct). - second, do you have any reference for your 'tada' <- 'voila' idea?

Comment: @Joe Blow: You were also trying to connect these two words in your now-deleted answer.  Provide actual historical evidence for this.  Surely there would be plenty, as this is a word that sprang up in the 1900s.

Comment: @Mitch - Hi Mitch, in france, you pronounce it "walla". (It just means "so" or "all done.")  In england, or especially the US .. I think I would probably say "v" [and in fact, "voiah-la", not so much "volla"] because that is more how english speakers pronounce it.  I do not have any reference - it was an idea to discuss. The OED guess is comic.  The citation is a good one but could go either way. And I ...

Comment: @Kosmo Hi Kosmo!  ...I just deleted the section as internet arguments where people get bitsy over their position, are for idiots. If you are bitter that I deleted it the last comment was "Finally, regarding the dadaist OED theory. ("This word came about by people imitating a music hall / quiz show / err-something musical sting!") To support this theory, it seems to me one would have to show that that "musical sting" (as we would call such a thing today), was commonly used before (say) 1900. Wouldn't you agree? I just dunno if that is very plausible, you know?"  I await the evidence.

Comment: @Joe Blow: As you see in my answer, the first citation of *tada* ever found by English etymologists is talking explicitly about how it is an onomatopoeia of the musical sting.  It's actually amazing how on-the-nose it is.  And, though you have said it is a "bizarre" etymology, you have given no reason why; and in fact, it is not strange at all.  On the other hand, you have provided absolutely zero evidence for your *voila* theory, here or in your deleted answer, and quite frankly, the burden is on you to at least come up with *some* piece of actual, hard evidence.

Comment: @kosmo Hi Kosmo! Hmm, the citation you give would work perfectly as a joke regardless of the origin of the word.  The strange *"it's an imitation of a musical hall sound effect!"* theory is strange for the clear reasons I mentioned.  I have no evidence at all for my notion, other than that the sound and meaning is the same, and there are a number of "sound alikes" such as that from french. Cheers

Comment: @Kosmonaut, @Joe: If it can be of any use, *tada* is use as a trumpet onomatopoeia in Italy too. I know nothing about its origins however.

Comment: It appeared in my favorite Mozart symphony 36 (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tY6u4czVvkE). Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._36_%28Mozart%29) states that Mozart wrote the symphony in 4 days, in anticipating a Count in Linz's up coming announcement. Interesting stuff!!

Answer (score -4):

I heard that the origin of "ta dah!" was in India, where in some language or idiom it meant "It's perfect just the way it is."

Comment: But "I heard" is not a very good reference!

Comment: ...and 'some language or idiom' is maximally vague.

Answer (score -5):

From the old celebratory Te Deums in Latin I thought?

Comment: Do you have a reference or a particular reason you think this is the case?