# Is there any link between tada and toda--Hebrew for thank you?

Tags: etymology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Origin of ‘tada’](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33564/origin-of-tada)

Someone told me that Tada may have come from Toda--which is Hebrew for thank you.   Did anyone else ever hear of that possible origin?

Comment: For me, *Tada!* is the sound of a fanfare, a trumpet announcing something excellent and noteworthy. Is there any other meaning?

Comment: Is there any additional motivation for this idea? something like "Tada canme out of the vaudeville tradition, and vaudeville had a high percentage of Yiddish speakers of which 'tada' was borrowed into Yiddish via Hebrew". I do not have a clue if this is even remotely the case, but is the kind of motivation that would help. Plain phonetic resemblance is not enough. 'bad in English and 'bad' in Hindi both mean 'not good', but they are in no way etymologically related.