# Word for arms "outstretched, overhead, in y-shape"?

Tags: meaning

Just as "arms akimbo" has a very specific meaning, is there an "arms __" that specifically means what I described in the title?

Comment: TOUCHDOWN!!!!!!

Comment: Does [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28137/one-word-for-the-ta-daa-pose) help?

Comment: akimbY !!!!!!!!

Comment: @simchona Helps, but not _quite_ the same scenario. That question is about something more like the motion a magician takes after the reveal. A key difference there being hands outstretched to the _side_.

Comment: @xanadont: Ok, I just wanted to make sure it wasn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a single word that describes this. When I read your question, my first thought was the line from Pearl Jam's *Jeremy*: `arms raised in a V`

Among friends, I jokingly refer to this pose as *sticking the landing* (as a gymnast might). *YMCA interruptus* is sillier and not as clear, but remains an amusing option.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate the gymnast reference as I thought of this too. Initially I had a problem with it since gymnasts "raise their arms in a V" regardless of sticking the landing or not; it's used to signal the end of the routine. Of course that's neither here nor there since it's immediately clear what "sticks the landing" means.

Answer (score 3):

Not one word, but I'd say you hit the nail squarely on the head in the question when you said *arms overhead in a Y-shape*.

I instantly knew exactly what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

as a [flight deck hand signal](http://navysite.de/cvn/catcom.htm) it means/called "fold" or "spread wings"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

People often use "raised (as if) in supplication" to describe that position, which can go from a "Y" shape to straight overhead.

I don't know if there's a precise word for it, though.  I'm curious to see if there is.

Answer (score 1):

"[upraised arms](http://www.google.com/search?q=upraised+arms&hl=en&tbm=isch)" or "[arms upraised](http://www.google.com/search?q=arms+upraised&hl=en&tbm=isch)"