# What is it called when an antecedent noun follows the pronoun?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, pronouns, linguistics, antecedents

Here is the example that raised the question in my mind:

> He was splashing, enjoying the jungle's great joys, when Horton the elephant heard a small noise.

Here, *He* refers to *Horton*; but one cannot see that until one reads the rest of the sentence.  This contrasts with the normal placement of the nounal referent *before* the pronoun:

> Horton the elephant was splashing, enjoying the jungle's great joys, when he heard a small noise.

Of course, now the meter isn't nearly as pleasant, so that is presumably why the former was preferred.  However, it doesn't occur only in poetry.  What is this form called?

Comment: It still rhymes, but the meter is off.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's a [cataphor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cataphora).

[A cataphor is a phrase that is explained by text that comes *after* the phrase. Example: "Although he loved fishing, Paul went skating with his girlfriend." Here *he* is a cataphoric reference to *Paul*.](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/nlpdict.html#cataphor)

Comment: Now I need to ask you: did you already know that, or did you look it up, and if the latter, how?

Comment: I study computational linguistics. In this case, I knew it already. At other times, I have a better-than-average idea of where (and for what) to look.

Comment: Online or in a reference book?

Comment: Online. I like studying from books, but I don't find them all that usable as references (no Ctrl-F).

Comment: I heartily agree with the last sentiment.  Would you care to divulge your sources?

Comment: You can find all the course material at my uni's website at http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/kvv/. Go through http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/courses/FLST/2010/page.php?id=index for a general introduction. I often need to read papers from http://aclweb.org/anthology-new/, and so, I mirror the entire thing on my laptop. I have nothing against divulging my sources, but it's really too numerous to list the rest of them (and they are more specialized anyway).

Comment: +1 for what must be one of the shortest indisputably correct answers here on ELU. But you probably should have put a definition in your actual answer text, such as [a cataphor is a phrase that is explained by text that comes *after* the phrase](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/nlpdict.html).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I first thought of writing just one (linked) word. But I thought that would look rude, even though it suits the tag "single-word-requests". I like brevity :-).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I see you have enough reputation points here to edit my answer. Feel free to do it: I won't reject your edits. I just don't have the heart to make it longer myself.

Comment: Everybody gets one. But I ain't going round polishing your posts every time! :)

Comment: Now this one becomes my shortest answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40454/word-for-arms-outstretched-overhead-in-y-shape/40469 :-)