# "Those" used without antecedent

Tags: pronouns, antecedents

Is the sentence, "Bob asked those on his team a question" correct even though "those" doesn't really have an antecedent?

If it is not correct, what would be the best way to correct it?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I marked "no" for right now, since it feels slightly different, but I may be mistaken. "Those" is certainly explained by the phrase "on his team", but the word "players" or similar is not found anywhere in the sentence, thus I don't the other question quite answers mine as to whether my sentence is correct as is. Definitely provided info though. Thank you!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Looks like you edited your comment while I was typing. This makes sense now! Thank you! Is this different enough to merit a separate question? I certainly wouldn't have known without your comment.

Comment: Here, 'those on his team' is short for 'those players [etc] on his team' and 'those' is in the usual place for a determiner. An example showing obvious 'antecedent follows the pronoun referring to it' is ' "Would they believe him?" Bob asked himself.' // Does this answer your underlying question? [What is it called when an antecedent noun follows the pronoun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40579/what-is-it-called-when-an-antecedent-noun-follows-the-pronoun)

Comment: No; the cataphor example (eg 'Before they left, my parents asked me to look after the cat') has been covered. This is just looking at the phrase 'those on his team', not an ELU question. Here, 'those' is a pronoun typically post-modified, here by a PP. In 'Those who are about to die salute you', the post-modifier is a relative clause.

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed Even *Bob asked them.* would be grammatical. Although as a standalone sentence it wouldn't make much sense, because it doesn't say who they are.. Whether or not that's "correct" depend on how you're using that word. The sentence in the question does make sense as a standalone sentence.